# Is $f : A \to P(A), a \mapsto \{a\}$ injective or surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Given an arbitrary set $A$, let $f:A \to P(A)$ be the function defined for
all $a \in A$ by "$f(a) = \{a\}$".

How would you prove that $f$ is injective or surjective?

Comment: Can't be surjective because Cantor.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Right, and in this case Cantor gives us the set $\{a\in A:a\notin f(a)\}=\{a\in A:a\notin\{a\}\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Can you find any $a\in A$ that is sent to $\emptyset\in\wp(A)$? If not then you can conclude that $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we suppose that $a,b \in A$ and $f(a) = f(b)$, we get by definition that $\{a\} = \{b\}$. Do you agree that we can conclude from this that $a=b$, and that this proves injectivity?

As for surjectivity, you must decide whether *all* subsets of $A$ are of the form $\{a\}$ for some $a \in A$. Is this true?